# How to add a path with spaces as an arguments to CreateProcess batch file?

Tags: c++, batch-file, arguments, createprocess

I am trying to pass an argument with a space in i to a batch file I run via CreateProcess(). How do I specify that the entire object is an argument?

```
std::wstring args = TEXT("/C \"C:\\setup.bat\" C:\\TEST TEST");
```

In the example above, my batch file reads the first argument as C:\TEST.

And, this does not work (batch file exits immediately and does not run):

```
std::wstring args = TEXT("/C \"C:\\setup.bat\" \"C:\\TEST TEST\"");
```

Here is the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define WINDOWS_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

#include <strsafe.h>
#include <string>
#include <UserEnv.h>
#include <vector>

#define BUFSIZE 4096

#pragma comment(lib, "userenv.lib")

std::wstring GetEnvString()
{
    wchar_t* env = GetEnvironmentStrings();
    if (!env)
    {
        abort();
    }

    const wchar_t* var = env;
    size_t total_len = 0;
    size_t len;

    while ((len = wcslen(var)) > 0)
    {
        total_len += len + 1;
        var += len + 1;
    }

    std::wstring result(env, total_len);
    FreeEnvironmentStrings(env);
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    LPVOID env;

    if (!CreateEnvironmentBlock(&env, NULL, FALSE))
    {
        std::cout << "FAILURE" << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        abort();
    }

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));

    STARTUPINFO si;
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    std::wstring program = TEXT("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
    std::wstring args = TEXT("/C");

    args.append(TEXT(" \"C:\\setup.bat\""));
    args.append(TEXT(" C:\TEST TEST"));

    std::vector<wchar_t> buf(args.begin(), args.end());
    buf.push_back(0);

    if (!CreateProcess(program.c_str(), buf.data(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, env, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        std::cout << "FAILURE" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        abort();
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    DestroyEnvironmentBlock(env);


    if (!CreateEnvironmentBlock(&env, NULL, FALSE))
    {
        std::cout << "FAILURE" << std::endl;
        abort();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the /C parameter needs its entire parameter enclosed by quotes (if it contain spaces).
so, instead of `cmd /c "c:\setup.bat" "c:\test test"`, you need `cmd /c ""c:\setup.bat" "c:\test test""` (or at least `cmd /c "c:\setup.bat "c:\test test""`)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
std::wstring args = TEXT("/C");

args.append(TEXT(" \"\"C:\\setup.bat\""));
args.append(TEXT(" \"C:\\TEST TEST\""));
```

I figure this ends up doing something like: cmd.exe "C:\setup.bat "C:\Test Test""

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
std::wstring args = TEXT("/C \"C:\\setup.bat\" \"C:\\TEST\ TEST\"");
```

Comment: `"\ "` (with a space) is not a valid [escape sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Comment: Remove the escaped space and it should work. All you need are quotes around the path with spaces.

Comment: std::wstring args = TEXT("/C \"C:\\setup.bat\" "C:\\TEST TEST"");

??? That doesn't work. The " before C:\\TEST ends the " after TEXT("